# Javascript / Jquery Timelime addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline

Greetings,
I am curious if there is any good  plugin or project that allows users to add/remove event timegaps and pin the places and possibly generate some sort of output to save to the server side.

I have found  [today's timetable](http://www.cod3.net/timetable/) however it is not dynamic where users can slide between events or add new event to a time-gap. Either vertical or horizontal would be useful for me.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **[dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml)** is full featured nice looking and free for personal use.
- [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) full-sized, drag & drop calendar

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising: http://www.bytecyclist.com/projects/jmonthcalendar/

This might do AND it integrates with DB easily (or so they say): http://plugins.jquery.com/project/wdCalendar

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that's impressed me:

http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/

Answer (score 0):

> I have found today's timetable however it is not dynamic where users can slide between events or add new event to a time-gap. Either vertical or horizontal would be useful for me.

But it does!! Hover on the `<` & `>` buttons to slide and see on the link in your question:

Usage

- Initialize it
  `var nameOfYourVar = newTimetable("idOfYourDiv");`
- Add an event
  `nameOfYourVar.addEvent(htmlContents, startHour, duration, onClickFunction);`
- Make it scroll to a specific hour
  `nameOfYourVar.goTo(hour);`
- Hours are float numbers (ex: 14h30 = 14.30 or 14.3).

Please tell me if Ive not understood what your question?

Comment: *"it is not dynamic"* this was his biggest concern. You can't add/remove events like on Google calendar.

Comment: aha. I didn't realize there was no way to **remove** events! Sorry!